# Inline WebSVG doesn't have crisp lines?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg background that starts as separated then in 3 secs of page load, is moved to form the background. You can see a large triangle from the start that has rather poor quality and is very choppy, what could be the cause of this?

Here is a **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/zxbMVw/)** link for example.

**CSS**

```
html,
body,
.avatar {
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: block;
}
body {

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #4CB8C4 10%, #3CD3AD 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #4CB8C4 10%, #3CD3AD 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #4CB8C4 10%, #3CD3AD 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #4CB8C4 10%, #3CD3AD 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #4CB8C4 10%, #3CD3AD 90%); /* W3C */

}
.avatar {
  z-index: 800;
}
.avatar path {
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
      -ms-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
          transition: all 3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0);
          transform: translate(0);
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  -webkit-animation: p1 3s ease 1;
          animation: p1 3s ease 1;
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
  -webkit-animation: p2 3s ease 1;
          animation: p2 3s ease 1;
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
  -webkit-animation: p3 3s ease 1;
          animation: p3 3s ease 1;
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  -webkit-animation: p4 3s ease 1;
          animation: p4 3s ease 1;
}
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vw;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  margin-top: -20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: waitforit 0 ease-in 3s 1 forwards;
          animation: waitforit 0 ease-in 3s 1 forwards;
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(800%, 400%) rotate(-690deg) translateZ(0);
          transform: translate(800%, 400%) rotate(-690deg) translateZ(0);
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-700%, 600%) rotate(-720deg) translateZ(0);
          transform: translate(-700%, 600%) rotate(-720deg) translateZ(0);
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-900%, -500%) rotate(-820deg) translateZ(0);
          transform: translate(-900%, -500%) rotate(-820deg) translateZ(0);
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(700%, -800%) rotate(-950deg) translateZ(0);
          transform: translate(700%, -800%) rotate(-950deg) translateZ(0);
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  padding: 2px 0 0 4px;
  left: -50%;
  -webkit-animation: infromleft 0.5s ease-in 1 forwards;
          animation: infromleft 0.5s ease-in 1 forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes p1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes p2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes p3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes p4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
            transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes waitforit {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
@keyframes waitforit {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes infromleft {
  0% {
    left: -50%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes infromleft {
  0% {
    left: -50%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You use a PNG file as a source, I guess that's the reason.

Comment: I saved it out from illustrator as an SVG, and chose the get code option, is there anyway to save it out as an SVG completely?

Just figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so @Sirko pointed out it was using a PNG as a source, so this is partly credited to him.

I was changing the colors of my triangles earlier on in AI, and I clicked the gradient mesh tool and added extra points to my triangle, which in turn caused that single triangle to be treated as a .png.

Thanks for the help everyone, appreciate it!